# How to prevent sqlite3 UNIQUE constraint integrity error?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I want to be able to add multiple pieces of data to one `Product ID` that is defined as a primary key in one of my tables.

Below is where it is being created..

```
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Product
         (productid INTEGER primary key,
         name TEXT )''')
```

Tkinter then gets the values:

```
item1 = self.productidField.get() #variable 'item' used to define values entered into fields
item3 = self.nameField.get()
```

And then it is inserted..

```
c.execute("INSERT INTO Product VALUES (?, ?)", (item1, item3))
```

I want it so the `Product ID` defines the name.
E.G - I can add as many 'Chocolate Bars' ranging in flavour to a `Product ID` of `1` but if I try to add Strawberries, THEN I want the unique constraint to reject the `INSERT` process. At the moment, only one set of data can be added to a certain `Product ID`.

Comment: I think you should start by reading about what's a `primary key` in SQL. By definition, a primary key _is_ unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE product (product_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);

CREATE TABLE chocolate_bar (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    product_id INTEGER REFERENCES product (product_id),
    flavour TEXT
);
```

…or make the contents of the second table less specific.